# Existence of Integer Solutions for $e^a = b$ with $a \neq 0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there any pair of integers $a$ and $b$ such that $e^a = b$ for $a \neq 0$? I'm not quite sure how to even begin analyzing this equality. Has this problem been solved before?

Comment: Hello, have you heard about transcendental numbers ? In fact, we know that $e$ can't be a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. If $a > 0$ is such that $e^a = b$ for $b$ an integer, then $e$ is a root of $X^a - b$ which is impossible. If $a < 0$, then $e^{-a}$ is the inverse of $b$ so it is rational but it would imply that it is also a root of a polynomial with integer coefficients : absurd.

Comment: Congratulations on coming up with a really good question.  As the comment and answer show, the answer is: YES, this problem has been solved before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @NanoS has explained, the number $e$ is not just an irrational number, but it is also a transcendental number. A transcendental number is a real or complex number that is not algebraic - that is, not the root of any non-zero polynomial of finite degree with rational coefficients.

Indeed, it was proven that $e$ is transcendental by Charles Hermite in 1873. So, $e$ is already known to be transcendental, and you are raising it to an integer power $a$. The result $e^a$ will therefore also be transcendental by the [Lindemann Weierstrass Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem). Since all integers are algebraic numbers (they are solutions to simple polynomial equations like $x - n = 0, x \in \mathbb{Z}$), there is no integer $b$ that is equal to the transcendental number $e^a$ for any non-zero integer $a$.

Hence, there is no such pair of integers $a$ and $b$ that satisfy the equation $e^a = b$ for $a \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the references!

Comment: The reference to Lindemann-Weierstrass was unnecessary. The only important property is that $e$ is transcendental, so it cannot be a root of the polynomial $x^a-b$.